# Rigging a Stethoscope

Tags: rigging, bezier-curves

I’m trying to rig a Stethoscope and have come to this issue…

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have Hooks attached to a Bezier Curve but when i move a hook the end of the curve bends so it looks like it’s breaking the tube, is there any way to stop the end hooks from moving or rotating the end of the Curve?

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You might be able to adapt this tutorial about rigging a telephone cord to a stethoscope. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQs9f4x0gw.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce], upload your file or show more of your Hook and Curve settings. Are your curve control points set to **Aligned** mode?

Comment: Thanks,

looks like in the end all I had to do was shorten the left hand handle of the left bezier curve vertex and it worked but ill look at Aligned too.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer so others can benefit from it, please.